# "Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool' " ==TypeError

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i just want to update my favorite status in Firebase when user is click on favorite icon.
all is done! but when i fetch data i got this error:
"Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool' "
-isFavorite is a bool so what can i do?

here i got the error in this Function:

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts() async {
var url =
    'https://ecommerce-test-753ad-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken';
try {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  if (extractedData == {}) {
    return;
  }
  url =
      'https://ecommerce-test-753ad-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
  final favoriteResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
  final List<Product> loadedProduct = [];
  extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
    loadedProduct.add(
      Product(
        id: key,
        title: value['title'],
        price: value['price'],
        imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
        description: value['description'],
        isFavorite:
            favoriteData == null? false : favoriteData[key] ?? false,
      ),
    );
  });
  _productItems = loadedProduct;
  notifyListeners();
} catch (e) {
  rethrow;
}
}
```

this is product Model class:

```
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
 final String id;
 final String title;
 final double price;
 final String imageUrl;
 final String description;
 bool isFavorite;

 Product({
 required this.id,
 required this.title,
 required this.price,
 required this.imageUrl,
 required this.description,
 this.isFavorite = false,
  });


 void _setFavValue(bool newValue) {
  isFavorite = newValue;
  notifyListeners();
  }

Future<void> toggleFavoriteStatus(String authToken, String 
 userId) async {
  final oldStatus = isFavorite;
   isFavorite = !isFavorite;
  notifyListeners();
 final url =
     'https://ecommerce-test-753ad-default- 
rtdb.firebaseio.com/userFavorites/$userId/$id.json? 
auth=$authToken';
  try {
   final response = await http.put(
     Uri.parse(url),
    body: json.encode(isFavorite),
  );
  if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
    _setFavValue(oldStatus);
  }
} catch (error) {
  _setFavValue(oldStatus);
}
}
```

}

Comment: could you add your Product model class?

Comment: Check what `favoriteData[key]` is. Most likely this is a string and not a bool

Comment: @Ivo yes but i can pass the id , because here the key is the product id!

Comment: @MuhammadTawil I'm not saying anything about that, I understand that the key is the id. Just whatever is in `favoriteData[key]` is not a bool. You are assigning `favoriteData[key]` to `isFavorite` and you can only do that if `favoriteData[key]` is a bool

Comment: could you print what inside of favoriteData is?

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes : {-NAQTpO0QX4BEzkQaVdM: isFavorite}

Comment: @MuhammadTawil, do you mean `{"-NAQTpO0QX4BEzkQaVdM2": "isFavorite"}` or do you mean `{"-NAQTpO0QX4BEzkQaVdM2": isFavorite}`? You have to be clear with the " " signs! @eamirho3ein clearly interpreted it as the first option, with "isFavorite" as a String! But I don't think that's correct... is it? As you have earlier said, it's a bool. But you haven't put any " " marks even on the id, which IS a String, so it's not clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `favoriteData[key]` value that you get back from Firebase is in the form of a `String`, not a `bool` as you want it to be. Add these lines:

```
  extractedData.forEach((key, value) {

    // Two added lines:
    print('favoriteData[$key] is ${favoriteData[key]}');
    print('favoriteData[$key] is of type ${favoriteData[key].runtimeType}');

    loadedProduct.add(
      Product(
        id: key,
        title: value['title'],
        price: value['price'],
        imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
        description: value['description'],
        isFavorite:
            favoriteData == null? false : favoriteData[key] ?? false,
      ),
    );
```

That will tell you exactly what is in that variable. If the output is:

```
favoriteData[some_key] is true
favoriteData[some_key] is of type String
```

then you know that you have accidentally uploaded the value in the form of a the String 'true' rather than the bool value `true`. Maybe you have uploaded `'$isFavorite'` instead of `isFavorite` or something...?

If you find that the value contains something else entirely, neither 'true' nor 'false' nor 'null', then you'll think of next steps from there!  Hopefully, the print() will give you a clue, in any case.

---

Edit: Since you seem to be looking for a quick fix, try this instead:

change this :

```
extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
    loadedProduct.add(
      Product(
        id: key,
        title: value['title'],
        price: value['price'],
        imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
        description: value['description'],
        isFavorite:
            favoriteData == null? false : favoriteData[key] ?? false,
      ),
    );
  });
```

to this:

```
extractedData.forEach((key, value) {
    bool _isFavorite = favoriteData[key] != null && favoriteData[key] == 'true' ? true: false;
    loadedProduct.add(
      Product(
        id: key,
        title: value['title'],
        price: value['price'],
        imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
        description: value['description'],
        isFavorite: _isFavorite,
      ),
    );
  });
```

At least that's MORE likely to work than that other answer... if you REALLY can't tell us what's really inside that `favoriteData[key]` value of yours!

Comment: i got this :                                                                                                                                           I/flutter (12382): favoriteData[-NA7lSecAKu8vjE9nxYN] is null
I/flutter (12382): favoriteData[-NA7lSecAKu8vjE9nxYN] is of type Null

Comment: You got only one printout? Wasn't there ANY line that contained anything else than Null? Edit: Actually, there MUST be another line of printout, because a Null value wouldn't give the error that you have described, "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool' ". Search for "type String" in your logs!

Comment: yes just null  !

Comment: See my edited comment above.

Comment: If you do get the error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'bool' ", look at the lines just before that error in you logs... There, you will find a "type String", somewhere.

Comment: Oh, that worked?  That must mean that at some point in your logs, you got: " I/flutter (12382): favoriteData[some_key] is isFavorite I/flutter (12382): favoriteData[some_key] is of type String"....  And if you had told me that, I could have also suggested that fix! However, if you want it to BE a `bool` rather than the `String` `isFavorite`, you really should upload it as a `bool`! I.e. either `true` or `false`.

Comment: I've updated my answer above with another quick fix now. Feel free to try it! If it works, you may un-accept that other answer and accept mine. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247646/discussion-between-muhammad-tawil-and-karolina-hagegard).

Comment: its work , and UI Updated!! Thank you a lot

Comment: That's wonderful... That means that indeed, you HAD put the word 'true' in your variable, intead of the boolean value `true`. My quick fix will handle that problem, but a better solution would still be to do it right from the beginning, and actually upload the bool `true` to `favoriteData`! In any case, plz unaccept that other answer which was wrong, and accept mine. I would appreciate a lot! 